# How do chip designers determine how many decoupling capacitors are required?

Tags: integrated-circuit, decoupling-capacitor

When an IC designer has designed a new IC, how do they determine the necessary level of decoupling required for its power rails?  Do they just take a guess, or is there a more formalised/accurate method of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

The keywords you're looking for are Power Distribution Network (PDN) analysis.

In general, we can treat the supply(ies) as port(s), which consume some DC which we can ignore for AC purposes, and which emit AC due to dynamic current flows within the chip, and which are susceptible to changes in supply voltage from external causes and from the same current flows.  Thus, for a board design, we need some degree of filtering or regulation, and must provide a low enough impedance at the supply ports.

Design therefore considers filtering and regulation, and the impedance with respect to tolerable voltage change / ripple and AC load current, over all frequencies of concern to the design.

Note that it isn't very feasible to get extremely low impedances at high frequencies at the board level, which chip designers must account for internally -- whether in the package (onboard bypass) or on die (using enough alternating metal layers to increase supply capacitance).  Typically this is in the 10s to 100s MHz range, and higher frequencies must be handled internally.